# How to change date format dd/mm/yyyy in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have following format `mm/dd/yyyy` how to change that to `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
$(function () {
            $('#txtDocDOB').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true,
            });
});
```

Input type:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
                                                    <input id="txtDocDOB" type="text" value="10/24/1984" class="form-control">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
```

```js
/**
* @version: 2.1.19
* @author: Dan Grossman http://www.dangrossman.info/
* @copyright: Copyright (c) 2012-2015 Dan Grossman. All rights reserved.
* @license: Licensed under the MIT license. See http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* @website: https://www.improvely.com/
*/

(function(root, factory) {

  

    var DateRangePicker = function(element, options, cb) {

        //default settings for options
        this.parentEl = 'body';
        this.element = $(element);
        this.startDate = moment().startOf('day');
        this.endDate = moment().endOf('day');
        this.minDate = false;
        this.maxDate = false;
        this.dateLimit = false;
        this.autoApply = false;
        this.singleDatePicker = false;
        this.showDropdowns = false;
        this.showWeekNumbers = false;
        this.showISOWeekNumbers = false;
        this.timePicker = false;
        this.timePicker24Hour = false;
        this.timePickerIncrement = 1;
        this.timePickerSeconds = false;
        this.linkedCalendars = true;
        this.autoUpdateInput = true;
        this.alwaysShowCalendars = false;
        this.ranges = {};

        this.opens = 'right';
        if (this.element.hasClass('pull-right'))
            this.opens = 'left';

        this.drops = 'down';
        if (this.element.hasClass('dropup'))
            this.drops = 'up';

        this.buttonClasses = 'btn btn-sm';
        this.applyClass = 'btn-success';
        this.cancelClass = 'btn-default';

        this.locale = {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            separator: ' - ',
            applyLabel: 'Apply',
            cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
            weekLabel: 'W',
            customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
            daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
            monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
            firstDay: moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek()
        };

        this.callback = function() { };

        //some state information
        this.isShowing = false;
        this.leftCalendar = {};
        this.rightCalendar = {};

        //custom options from user
        if (typeof options !== 'object' || options === null)
            options = {};

        //allow setting options with data attributes
        //data-api options will be overwritten with custom javascript options
        options = $.extend(this.element.data(), options);

        //html template for the picker UI
        if (typeof options.template !== 'string' && !(options.template instanceof $))
            options.template = '<div class="daterangepicker dropdown-menu">' +
                '<div class="calendar left">' +
                    '<div class="daterangepicker_input">' +
                      '<input class="input-mini" type="text" name="daterangepicker_start" value="" />' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-calendar glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>' +
                      '<div class="calendar-time">' +
                        '<div></div>' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-clock-o glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="calendar-table"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="calendar right">' +
                    '<div class="daterangepicker_input">' +
                      '<input class="input-mini" type="text" name="daterangepicker_end" value="" />' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-calendar glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>' +
                      '<div class="calendar-time">' +
                        '<div></div>' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-clock-o glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="calendar-table"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="ranges">' +
                    '<div class="range_inputs">' +
                        '<button class="applyBtn" disabled="disabled" type="button"></button> ' +
                        '<button class="cancelBtn" type="button"></button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        

        //
        // handle all the possible options overriding defaults
        //

        

        if (typeof options.singleDatePicker === 'boolean') {
            this.singleDatePicker = options.singleDatePicker;
            if (this.singleDatePicker)
                this.endDate = this.startDate.clone();
        }

        

       
       
      

        if (this.singleDatePicker) {
            this.container.addClass('single');
            this.container.find('.calendar.left').addClass('single');
            this.container.find('.calendar.left').show();
            this.container.find('.calendar.right').hide();
            this.container.find('.daterangepicker_input input, .daterangepicker_input i').hide();
            if (!this.timePicker) {
                this.container.find('.ranges').hide();
            }
        }

        if ((typeof options.ranges === 'undefined' && !this.singleDatePicker) || this.alwaysShowCalendars) {
            this.container.addClass('show-calendar');
        }

        this.container.addClass('opens' + this.opens);

        //swap the position of the predefined ranges if opens right
        if (typeof options.ranges !== 'undefined' && this.opens == 'right') {
            var ranges = this.container.find('.ranges');
            var html = ranges.clone();
            ranges.remove();
            this.container.find('.calendar.left').parent().prepend(html);
        }

        //apply CSS classes and labels to buttons
        this.container.find('.applyBtn, .cancelBtn').addClass(this.buttonClasses);
        if (this.applyClass.length)
            this.container.find('.applyBtn').addClass(this.applyClass);
        if (this.cancelClass.length)
            this.container.find('.cancelBtn').addClass(this.cancelClass);
        this.container.find('.applyBtn').html(this.locale.applyLabel);
        this.container.find('.cancelBtn').html(this.locale.cancelLabel);

        //
        // event listeners
        //

        this.container.find('.calendar')
            .on('click.daterangepicker', '.prev', $.proxy(this.clickPrev, this))
            .on('click.daterangepicker', '.next', $.proxy(this.clickNext, this))
            .on('click.daterangepicker', 'td.available', $.proxy(this.clickDate, this))
            .on('mouseenter.daterangepicker', 'td.available', $.proxy(this.hoverDate, this))
            .on('mouseleave.daterangepicker', 'td.available', $.proxy(this.updateFormInputs, this))
            .on('change.daterangepicker', 'select.yearselect', $.proxy(this.monthOrYearChanged, this))
            .on('change.daterangepicker', 'select.monthselect', $.proxy(this.monthOrYearChanged, this))
            .on('change.daterangepicker', 'select.hourselect,select.minuteselect,select.secondselect,select.ampmselect', $.proxy(this.timeChanged, this))
            .on('click.daterangepicker', '.daterangepicker_input input', $.proxy(this.showCalendars, this))
            //.on('keyup.daterangepicker', '.daterangepicker_input input', $.proxy(this.formInputsChanged, this))
            .on('change.daterangepicker', '.daterangepicker_input input', $.proxy(this.formInputsChanged, this));

        this.container.find('.ranges')
            .on('click.daterangepicker', 'button.applyBtn', $.proxy(this.clickApply, this))
            .on('click.daterangepicker', 'button.cancelBtn', $.proxy(this.clickCancel, this))
            .on('click.daterangepicker', 'li', $.proxy(this.clickRange, this))
            .on('mouseenter.daterangepicker', 'li', $.proxy(this.hoverRange, this))
            .on('mouseleave.daterangepicker', 'li', $.proxy(this.updateFormInputs, this));

        if (this.element.is('input')) {
            this.element.on({
                'click.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.show, this),
                'focus.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.show, this),
                'keyup.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.elementChanged, this),
                'keydown.daterangepicker': $.proxy(this.keydown, this)
            });
        } else {
            this.element.on('click.daterangepicker', $.proxy(this.toggle, this));
        }

        //
        // if attached to a text input, set the initial value
        //

        if (this.element.is('input') && !this.singleDatePicker && this.autoUpdateInput) {
            this.element.val(this.startDate.format(this.locale.format) + this.locale.separator + this.endDate.format(this.locale.format));
            this.element.trigger('change');
        } else if (this.element.is('input') && this.autoUpdateInput) {
            this.element.val(this.startDate.format(this.locale.format));
            this.element.trigger('change');
        }

    };

    DateRangePicker.prototype = {

        constructor: DateRangePicker,

        setStartDate: function(startDate) {
            if (typeof startDate === 'string')
                this.startDate = moment(startDate, this.locale.format);

            if (typeof startDate === 'object')
                this.startDate = moment(startDate);

            if (!this.timePicker)
                this.startDate = this.startDate.startOf('day');

            if (this.timePicker && this.timePickerIncrement)
                this.startDate.minute(Math.round(this.startDate.minute() / this.timePickerIncrement) * this.timePickerIncrement);

            if (this.minDate && this.startDate.isBefore(this.minDate))
                this.startDate = this.minDate;

            if (this.maxDate && this.startDate.isAfter(this.maxDate))
                this.startDate = this.maxDate;

            if (!this.isShowing)
                this.updateElement();

            this.updateMonthsInView();
        },

        setEndDate: function(endDate) {
            if (typeof endDate === 'string')
                this.endDate = moment(endDate, this.locale.format);

            if (typeof endDate === 'object')
                this.endDate = moment(endDate);

            if (!this.timePicker)
                this.endDate = this.endDate.endOf('day');

            if (this.timePicker && this.timePickerIncrement)
                this.endDate.minute(Math.round(this.endDate.minute() / this.timePickerIncrement) * this.timePickerIncrement);

            if (this.endDate.isBefore(this.startDate))
                this.endDate = this.startDate.clone();

            if (this.maxDate && this.endDate.isAfter(this.maxDate))
                this.endDate = this.maxDate;

            if (this.dateLimit && this.startDate.clone().add(this.dateLimit).isBefore(this.endDate))
                this.endDate = this.startDate.clone().add(this.dateLimit);

            this.previousRightTime = this.endDate.clone();

            if (!this.isShowing)
                this.updateElement();

            this.updateMonthsInView();
        },

        isInvalidDate: function() {
            return false;
        },

        updateView: function() {
            if (this.timePicker) {
                this.renderTimePicker('left');
                this.renderTimePicker('right');
                if (!this.endDate) {
                    this.container.find('.right .calendar-time select').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    this.container.find('.right .calendar-time select').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }
            if (this.endDate) {
                this.container.find('input[name="daterangepicker_end"]').removeClass('active');
                this.container.find('input[name="daterangepicker_start"]').addClass('active');
            } else {
                this.container.find('input[name="daterangepicker_end"]').addClass('active');
                this.container.find('input[name="daterangepicker_start"]').removeClass('active');
            }
            this.updateMonthsInView();
            this.updateCalendars();
            this.updateFormInputs();
        },

        updateMonthsInView: function() {
            if (this.endDate) {

                //if both dates are visible already, do nothing
                if (!this.singleDatePicker && this.leftCalendar.month && this.rightCalendar.month &&
                    (this.startDate.format('YYYY-MM') == this.leftCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM') || this.startDate.format('YYYY-MM') == this.rightCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM'))
                    &&
                    (this.endDate.format('YYYY-MM') == this.leftCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM') || this.endDate.format('YYYY-MM') == this.rightCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM'))
                    ) {
                    return;
                }

                this.leftCalendar.month = this.startDate.clone().date(2);
                if (!this.linkedCalendars && (this.endDate.month() != this.startDate.month() || this.endDate.year() != this.startDate.year())) {
                    this.rightCalendar.month = this.endDate.clone().date(2);
                } else {
                    this.rightCalendar.month = this.startDate.clone().date(2).add(1, 'month');
                }
                
            } else {
                if (this.leftCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM') != this.startDate.format('YYYY-MM') && this.rightCalendar.month.format('YYYY-MM') != this.startDate.format('YYYY-MM')) {
                    this.leftCalendar.month = this.startDate.clone().date(2);
                    this.rightCalendar.month = this.startDate.clone().date(2).add(1, 'month');
                }
            }
        },

        updateCalendars: function() {

            if (this.timePicker) {
                var hour, minute, second;
                if (this.endDate) {
                    hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .hourselect').val(), 10);
                    minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .minuteselect').val(), 10);
                    second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.left .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
                        var ampm = this.container.find('.left .ampmselect').val();
                        if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
                            hour += 12;
                        if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
                            hour = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .hourselect').val(), 10);
                    minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .minuteselect').val(), 10);
                    second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.right .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
                        var ampm = this.container.find('.right .ampmselect').val();
                        if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
                            hour += 12;
                        if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
                            hour = 0;
                    }
                }
                this.leftCalendar.month.hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
                this.rightCalendar.month.hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
            }

            this.renderCalendar('left');
            this.renderCalendar('right');

            //highlight any predefined range matching the current start and end dates
            this.container.find('.ranges li').removeClass('active');
            if (this.endDate == null) return;

            this.calculateChosenLabel();
        },

        renderCalendar: function(side) {

            //
            // Build the matrix of dates that will populate the calendar
            //

            var calendar = side == 'left' ? this.leftCalendar : this.rightCalendar;
            var month = calendar.month.month();
            var year = calendar.month.year();
            var hour = calendar.month.hour();
            var minute = calendar.month.minute();
            var second = calendar.month.second();
            var daysInMonth = moment([year, month]).daysInMonth();
            var firstDay = moment([year, month, 1]);
            var lastDay = moment([year, month, daysInMonth]);
            var lastMonth = moment(firstDay).subtract(1, 'month').month();
            var lastYear = moment(firstDay).subtract(1, 'month').year();
            var daysInLastMonth = moment([lastYear, lastMonth]).daysInMonth();
            var dayOfWeek = firstDay.day();

            //initialize a 6 rows x 7 columns array for the calendar
            var calendar = [];
            calendar.firstDay = firstDay;
            calendar.lastDay = lastDay;

            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                calendar[i] = [];
            }

            //populate the calendar with date objects
            var startDay = daysInLastMonth - dayOfWeek + this.locale.firstDay + 1;
            if (startDay > daysInLastMonth)
                startDay -= 7;

            if (dayOfWeek == this.locale.firstDay)
                startDay = daysInLastMonth - 6;

            var curDate = moment([lastYear, lastMonth, startDay, 12, minute, second]);

            var col, row;
            for (var i = 0, col = 0, row = 0; i < 42; i++, col++, curDate = moment(curDate).add(24, 'hour')) {
                if (i > 0 && col % 7 === 0) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }
                calendar[row][col] = curDate.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
                curDate.hour(12);

                if (this.minDate && calendar[row][col].format('YYYY-MM-DD') == this.minDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') && calendar[row][col].isBefore(this.minDate) && side == 'left') {
                    calendar[row][col] = this.minDate.clone();
                }

                if (this.maxDate && calendar[row][col].format('YYYY-MM-DD') == this.maxDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') && calendar[row][col].isAfter(this.maxDate) && side == 'right') {
                    calendar[row][col] = this.maxDate.clone();
                }

            }

            //make the calendar object available to hoverDate/clickDate
            if (side == 'left') {
                this.leftCalendar.calendar = calendar;
            } else {
                this.rightCalendar.calendar = calendar;
            }

            //
            // Display the calendar
            //

            var minDate = side == 'left' ? this.minDate : this.startDate;
            var maxDate = this.maxDate;
            var selected = side == 'left' ? this.startDate : this.endDate;

            var html = '<table class="table-condensed">';
            html += '<thead>';
            html += '<tr>';

            // add empty cell for week number
            if (this.showWeekNumbers || this.showISOWeekNumbers)
                html += '<th></th>';

            if ((!minDate || minDate.isBefore(calendar.firstDay)) && (!this.linkedCalendars || side == 'left')) {
                html += '<th class="prev available"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></th>';
            } else {
                html += '<th></th>';
            }

            var dateHtml = this.locale.monthNames[calendar[1][1].month()] + calendar[1][1].format(" YYYY");

            if (this.showDropdowns) {
                var currentMonth = calendar[1][1].month();
                var currentYear = calendar[1][1].year();
                var maxYear = (maxDate && maxDate.year()) || (currentYear + 5);
                var minYear = (minDate && minDate.year()) || (currentYear - 50);
                var inMinYear = currentYear == minYear;
                var inMaxYear = currentYear == maxYear;

                var monthHtml = '<select class="monthselect">';
                for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
                    if ((!inMinYear || m >= minDate.month()) && (!inMaxYear || m <= maxDate.month())) {
                        monthHtml += "<option value='" + m + "'" +
                            (m === currentMonth ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                            ">" + this.locale.monthNames[m] + "</option>";
                    } else {
                        monthHtml += "<option value='" + m + "'" +
                            (m === currentMonth ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                            " disabled='disabled'>" + this.locale.monthNames[m] + "</option>";
                    }
                }
                monthHtml += "</select>";

                var yearHtml = '<select class="yearselect">';
                for (var y = minYear; y <= maxYear; y++) {
                    yearHtml += '<option value="' + y + '"' +
                        (y === currentYear ? ' selected="selected"' : '') +
                        '>' + y + '</option>';
                }
                yearHtml += '</select>';

                dateHtml = monthHtml + yearHtml;
            }

            html += '<th colspan="5" class="month">' + dateHtml + '</th>';
            if ((!maxDate || maxDate.isAfter(calendar.lastDay)) && (!this.linkedCalendars || side == 'right' || this.singleDatePicker)) {
                html += '<th class="next available"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></th>';
            } else {
                html += '<th></th>';
            }

            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<tr>';

            // add week number label
            if (this.showWeekNumbers || this.showISOWeekNumbers)
                html += '<th class="week">' + this.locale.weekLabel + '</th>';

            $.each(this.locale.daysOfWeek, function(index, dayOfWeek) {
                html += '<th>' + dayOfWeek + '</th>';
            });

            html += '</tr>';
            html += '</thead>';
            html += '<tbody>';

            //adjust maxDate to reflect the dateLimit setting in order to
            //grey out end dates beyond the dateLimit
            if (this.endDate == null && this.dateLimit) {
                var maxLimit = this.startDate.clone().add(this.dateLimit).endOf('day');
                if (!maxDate || maxLimit.isBefore(maxDate)) {
                    maxDate = maxLimit;
                }
            }

            for (var row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
                html += '<tr>';

                // add week number
                if (this.showWeekNumbers)
                    html += '<td class="week">' + calendar[row][0].week() + '</td>';
                else if (this.showISOWeekNumbers)
                    html += '<td class="week">' + calendar[row][0].isoWeek() + '</td>';

                for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {

                    var classes = [];

                    //highlight today's date
                    if (calendar[row][col].isSame(new Date(), "day"))
                        classes.push('today');

                    //highlight weekends
                    if (calendar[row][col].isoWeekday() > 5)
                        classes.push('weekend');

                    //grey out the dates in other months displayed at beginning and end of this calendar
                    if (calendar[row][col].month() != calendar[1][1].month())
                        classes.push('off');

                    //don't allow selection of dates before the minimum date
                    if (this.minDate && calendar[row][col].isBefore(this.minDate, 'day'))
                        classes.push('off', 'disabled');

                    //don't allow selection of dates after the maximum date
                    if (maxDate && calendar[row][col].isAfter(maxDate, 'day'))
                        classes.push('off', 'disabled');

                    //don't allow selection of date if a custom function decides it's invalid
                    if (this.isInvalidDate(calendar[row][col]))
                        classes.push('off', 'disabled');

                    //highlight the currently selected start date
                    if (calendar[row][col].format('YYYY-MM-DD') == this.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
                        classes.push('active', 'start-date');

                    //highlight the currently selected end date
                    if (this.endDate != null && calendar[row][col].format('YYYY-MM-DD') == this.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
                        classes.push('active', 'end-date');

                    //highlight dates in-between the selected dates
                    if (this.endDate != null && calendar[row][col] > this.startDate && calendar[row][col] < this.endDate)
                        classes.push('in-range');

                    var cname = '', disabled = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                        cname += classes[i] + ' ';
                        if (classes[i] == 'disabled')
                            disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (!disabled)
                        cname += 'available';

                    html += '<td class="' + cname.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') + '" data-title="' + 'r' + row + 'c' + col + '">' + calendar[row][col].date() + '</td>';

                }
                html += '</tr>';
            }

            html += '</tbody>';
            html += '</table>';

            this.container.find('.calendar.' + side + ' .calendar-table').html(html);

        },

        

}));
```

Comment: Just a suggestion.... The  [Bootstrap Date time picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) is way simpler & has lots of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try adding local format to your daterangepicker?

```
$('#txtDocDOB').daterangepicker({
   locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
   },
   singleDatePicker: true,
   showDropdowns: true,
});
```

Comment: same problem @ Monkey_Dev1400

Comment: in your jsFiddle.net Example MM/DD/YYYY format only display

Comment: i need DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: in your input value name it 24/10/1984...I think what is cause it to display invalid date is do to the incorrect format of your value https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/rLnycn80/236/